# Random from list but show the same one for a period of one day, then random new one the next

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I am using Umbraco, which uses MVC Razor. But this question is a general C# .Random() question.

I have a Random pull from a list for a "Featured Item".  I get the list, find the next and then display it. However, this pulls on every browser refresh.  What I need is for the "featured item" to show for the whole day, then the next day, pull a new random item from the list.

My code so far to pull the random node is below.  How would I extend this to only pull the random item once per day, then the next day pull a new one.  Can this be done solely with C# or is Javascript going to be a better avenue. 
I thought of both, but how would I do the random pull once a day using C# MVC Razor?

```
var random = new Random();
var fCollectList = Umbraco.Content(7471).Descendants("featuredItem");
  int index = random.Next(fCollectList.Count());
//NEED TO SHOW THE SAME ONE FOR EVERYONE ON A DAY, THEN THE NEXT DAY SHOW ANOTHER RANDOM ONE. 
<p>@fCollectList[index].Name</p>
```

Comment: You should cache that value with 24h expiration.

Comment: How would I cache the value? C#, Javascript.  I don't know how to do it in C#

Comment: Singleton pattern search it

Comment: By the any other way you are doomed and try some solid searching too

Comment: If you are in umbraco you can use this helper:  @Html.CachedPartial("PartialView", MyModel, 3600, true);

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested in comments you need to cache the value somewhere but how you gonna cache it depends on your requirement.

If you want the same value for all of your users then the best thing is to store it in database, inside the table you will have `Value` and `CreatedAt` columns, on each refresh you will check if `CreatedAt` is today then just return `Value` otherwise generate new value and update the record with new `Value` and `CreatedAt`.

If you want different value for each user then you could do the same as above just with an extra column call `UserId` or do it in javascript by storing the `Value` and `CreatedAt` inside the localstorage, then you can apply same value generation logic as above but in javascript side.